# writing a label in R for a plot using text, and subscripts using either bquote, paste or expression

Tags: r, label, subscript

I am having some difficulty with the use of quote, paste and expression. 
I use a package that gives me some plot based on some results obtained from a data file. The results are saved as objects (`MIN.ED` and `MIN.error`).
For the plot, I would like to label some of the lines on the plot using those result objects as well as text.

For the label I use the following

```
line1abel<-paste("MAM"[3],MIN.ED,"\U00B1",MIN.error)
```

I have tried variants using 
`"MAM"["3"}`or
`"MAM[3]"`and keep on getting NA.

MAM is the model type and 3 is the number of parameters used for that model.
I would like that to appear as MAM subscript3 but all I get is  NA followed by the value for MIN.ED ± value for MIN.error.

I have looked right through the different subscript posts and I really cannot see why I get that NA value. I see that some posts use `bquote`, and others `expressions` etc, but with the plotting package, I need to to give the line labels as `line.labels=c(line1lable,line2label...)`

How can build the label expression with the text MAM and subscript "3" and why is it that I get a "NA"? I thought paste allowed to link effectively text and results as text and that at worst I would have had MAM[3] 44 ± 2 rather than NA 44 ± 2!

Answer (score 0):

```
MAM <- "text"
grid::grid.text(bquote(.(MAM)[3]))
```