# Subscripts when using bquote in geom_text followed by text

Tags: ggplot2

I've been looking through stackoverflow for the past few hours and couldn't find a solution which works for my problem.

The issue: I'm trying to use geom_text to manually write in a manually calculated value, which is fine when I just write the value and its unit using bquote (for example just writing 4.4µm is fine). However, I would like to write out **D[g]= 4.4µm** (with the g subsetted!) in the top left corner using geom_text. But once I start trying to add a subscript to it, it doesn't work and I get one of the following errors:

```
Error: Don't know how to add RHS to theme object 
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (14): label
Error: unexpected string constant in:
" #geom_text(label = bquote("D" [g] "= 4.4µm"), x = -.3, y = 900, size = 10)  +
  geom_text(label = bquote(D[g]"=4.4µm"
```

Here is the code I've been using thus far:

```
A = structure(list(`Size (µm)` = c(0.85, 0.85, 1.6, 1.6, 2.7, 2.7, 
4, 4, 5.85, 5.85, 9, 9, 20, 20), `C/dlogd` = c(0, 70.7482842209313, 
70.7482842209313, 147.721992341133, 147.721992341133, 752.133343128365, 
752.133343128365, 296.076678012312, 296.076678012312, 226.648066580862, 
226.648066580862, 302.286593848111, 302.286593848111, 0), `+s` = c(0, 
175.47011068069, 175.47011068069, 243.15534458114, 243.15534458114, 
1007.91042406178, 1007.91042406178, 439.475898343651, 439.475898343651, 
366.578774657598, 366.578774657598, 385.065980566499, 385.065980566499, 
0), `-s` = c(0, -33.9735422388272, -33.9735422388272, 52.2886401011273, 
52.2886401011273, 496.356262194949, 496.356262194949, 152.677457680973, 
152.677457680973, 86.7173585041254, 86.7173585041254, 219.507207129723, 
219.507207129723, 0), Sampling = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), Date = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("21st of February 2019", 
"19th of June 2019", "3rd of July 2019", "17th of July 2019"), class = "factor"), 
    Datenoyear = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("21st of February", "19th of June", 
    "3rd of July", "17th of July"), class = "factor"), DateNumber = c(21.2, 
    21.2, 21.2, 21.2, 21.2, 21.2, 21.2, 21.2, 21.2, 21.2, 21.2, 
    21.2, 21.2, 21.2)), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))



ggplot(A, aes(x=  `Size (µm)`)) + 
geom_line(aes(y = `C/dlogd`), size = 1.5) + 
  geom_line(aes(y =  `+s`), linetype = "twodash", color = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(y =  `-s`), linetype = "dashed" , color = "blue") +
  geom_point(aes(y =  `+s`), color = "red") +
  geom_point(aes(y = `C/dlogd`)) +
  geom_point(aes(y =  `-s`), color = "blue") +
  scale_x_log10(limits = c(0.4,21)) +
 #geom_text(label = bquote("D" [g] "= 4.4µm"), x = -.3, y = 900, size = 10)  + #gives the second error
  #geom_text(label = bquote(D[g]"=4.4µm"), x = -.1, y = 900, size = 10) + #gives the 3rd error
 # geom_text(label = bquote("4.4µm"), x = -0.3, y = 900, size = 10) +  #No error, but doesn't give me the "D[g] = " I need
  theme_bw() +
  annotation_logticks(side = "b") +
  facet_grid(~Datenoyear) +
  xlab(element_blank()) +
  ylab(element_blank())
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong? I've tried looking at these solutions: 
http://rchaeology.blogspot.com/2012/11/combining-superscripts-subscripts-and.html

https://community.rstudio.com/t/use-bquote-in-ggplot2-for-subscript-text/40882

[writing a label in R for a plot using text, and subscripts using either bquote, paste or expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40326969/writing-a-label-in-r-for-a-plot-using-text-and-subscripts-using-either-bquote)

But unfortunately none of them have worked. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't tell you what the problem is with your code. But instead of using `bquote` the  desired result can be achieved using `as.character(expression(paste(D[g], "=4.4µm")))`. Source: see [here](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/136237_170402e5f0b54561bf7605bdea98267a.html). Try this:

```
ggplot(A, aes(x=  `Size (µm)`)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = `C/dlogd`), size = 1.5) + 
  geom_line(aes(y =  `+s`), linetype = "twodash", color = "red") +
  geom_line(aes(y =  `-s`), linetype = "dashed" , color = "blue") +
  geom_point(aes(y =  `+s`), color = "red") +
  geom_point(aes(y = `C/dlogd`)) +
  geom_point(aes(y =  `-s`), color = "blue") +
  geom_text(label = as.character(expression(paste(D[g], "=4.4µm"))), parse = TRUE, x = -.1, y = 900, size = 10) + #gives the 3rd error
  scale_x_log10(limits = c(0.4, 21)) +
  theme_bw() +
  annotation_logticks(side = "b") +
  facet_grid(~Datenoyear) +
  xlab(element_blank()) +
  ylab(element_blank())
```